# clear ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am using an `ExpandableListView` along with a `ViewPager` so in `onPageSelected()` I need to clear the list.

I know one way to do it for a `ListView` is `setAdapter(null)` but I get `The method setAdapter(ListAdapter) is ambiguous for the type ExpandableListView` error if I try it on `ExpandableListView`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried inputting an empty adapter? Something like the following:

```
ExpandableListAdapter adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(); //or what ever adapter you use/created
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is not a null adapter and you will not get a null pointer. The adapter will contain no elements to display/show/populate.

You can check if the `adapter` is empty by calling `isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 11):

Try by type casting null with BaseExpandableListAdapter like below.

```
listview.setAdapter((BaseExpandableListAdapter)null);
```